# Electron: How Remove "DefaultProtocolClient" during uninstall?

Tags: electron

We have an Electron app that registers its self for a custom protocol:

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(customUrlProtocol)
```

This works great.  However, is there a way to remove this when someone uninstalls the app?  Need to work for both Mac and Windows

Comment: For windows you can use the uninstall event in [`electron-squirrel-startup`](https://github.com/electron-archive/grunt-electron-installer#handling-squirrel-events). Not sure about Mac though.